# Modelled air pollution data for UK at monthly resolution

Tags: data-request, uk, environment

I have found background data at the right spatial resolution from:

http://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/data/pcm-data

However this is by year, I ideally need the same data by month.

There is a lot of site-specific Automatic Urban and Rural Network (AURN) data available from DEFRA which goes down to hourly observations. Although, I would expect it would be extremely challenging to get this data into a monthly 1km gridded dataset...